# Counting number of records with condition

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a dataframe with an ID column and I want R to count the number of observations NOT containing the dot character.

Here is a small data sample:

```
df <- structure(list(ID =  c("1111.AA","2222.CC","7891.DD","0055","00111.ZZ","00235.WQ", "UUUT", "0057.A", "1100")), .Names=c("ID"), 
            row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = ("data.frame"))
```

R should return 3 based on this sample.

Comment: My bad, I edited the post. I meant observations not containing a dot character.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple ways to find this out.

We can find number of observations in `ID` that has a dot character using `grepl` and then invert the results and get the `sum`

```
sum(!grepl("\\.", df$ID))
#[1] 3
```

If we want the values instead

```
df[!grepl("\\.", df$ID),]
#[1] "0055" "UUUT" "1100"
```

---

Using `grep` with `invert = TRUE`

```
length(grep("\\.", df$ID, invert = TRUE))
#[1] 3

grep("\\.", df$ID, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
#[1] "0055" "UUUT" "1100"
```

---

Using `str_count` from `stringr` package

```
library(stringr)
sum(!str_count(df$ID, "\\."))
#[1] 3

df[!str_count(df$ID, "\\."), ]
#[1] "0055" "UUUT" "1100"
```

Comment: First solution can be freed of regex and made faster: `sum(!grepl(".", df$ID, fixed = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0):

```
length(which(!grepl('\\.',df$ID)))
```